# how to show custom dialog in random times android?

Tags: java, android, random, dialog

i'm developing a gift coupons android application and i want the user to have a custom dialog opens in random times if the application is on any ideas to run a task opens the dialog every random time. i have tried BroadcastReceiver but couldn't finish it that way

Comment: Please add some code of what you arleady have and already tried, so people on stackoverflow can halp you better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use android service like this:

1- create new java class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // your code
    return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

2-put your code in `onStartCommand`

3-add this to your manifest:`<service android:name="MyService" >`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.NextActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_next" >
    </activity>
    <service android:name="MyService" >
    </service>
</application>
```

4-call it when you want:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: that's ok but how i call it randomly